# Why don't I see timestamp in Google analytics Query Explorer

Tags: time, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

As per google analytics GA360 [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en), Why Can't we see the Visitor time-stamp dimension both on Front End and on Query Explorer

Query Explorer: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

My Intention is to know/find Page tracking time-stamp w.r.t seconds not in DateHourMinute

Do we need to implement the custom Dimension as stamp-time like(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:mmm) ?

Answer (score 2):

The [Google Analytics Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) makes its calls via the google analytics API.  The Google Analytics API has a list of valid [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) time stamp is not one of these.  valid [Time dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time)

My advice would be yes create your own custom dimension using either a stamp like that or unix time its up to you how you do it or how you want to use it.  You will then be able to access it though the [custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=custom_variables_or_columns)

Comment: @DalmTo Is the dateHourMinute dimension here based on a universal time? or the local time I sent the events? I dont see this in the docs. My app is sending from Singapore.

Comment: @iori24, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604693/google-analytics-query-explorer-is-datehourminute-a-standard-time-or-local

Comment: @iori24 the time returned byt Google analytics is relative to the time your google analytics account is set to.