# Google Analytics Query Explorer: Is dateHourMinute a standard time or local?

Tags: google-analytics

Im sending events in my app from Singapore. I want to know if the dateHourMinute column in Query Explorer is the exact local time I sent the events or is it a standard time? universal time? Do I need to add 8 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time it is shown is the time you selected for the view.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en